# loginButton.setReadPermissions(permissions)

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I am not able to understand the use of "setReadPermissions" method in a login button:

```
LoginButton loginButton = findViewById(R.id.login_button);
loginButton.setReadPermissions(permissions);
```

for implementing facebook login?

Comment: Have you read this carefully: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/ ?

Comment: Yes, I guess so. This document do not explain the meaning of the codes like the google developers page.

Comment: i suggest reading this too: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api

Comment: I can not find anything about setReadPermission on a login button there too.